# Getting the charging state of laptop with python on window

Tags: python, windows

In my laptop, **Window 7** is installed. I want to know whether my laptop is **connected to charger or not using python**.

Comment: How can you use python script to check if your laptop is not using python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the charging state, you can use the built-in `psutil` library or a 3rd party [`power` library](https://github.com/Kentzo/Power).

I am on AC power right now.

### power

**Installation** -

```
pip install power
```

**Usage** -

```
import power
source = power.PowerManagement().get_providing_power_source_type()
source == power.POWER_TYPE_AC
# True
source == power.POWER_TYPE_BATTERY
# False
source == power.POWER_TYPE_UPS
# False
```

## psutil

Does not seem to be very reliable, v5.2.1 -

```
import psutil
psutil.sensors_battery()
# sbattery(percent=0.0, secsleft=-1, power_plugged=None)
psutil.sensors_battery().power_plugged
# None
```

Comment: can you explain how does it work. Also all outputs are same for both case, that is, when charger is connected or disconnected.

Comment: Which case, which library? Refer to the github repo for `power`. For `psutil`, there isn't much you can do about it because they themselves say that the functionality is not for production yet. You can check source code for both.

Comment: **psutil** worked for me. I just wanted the **power_plugged** value.